# Reaching Spa from Charleroi/other aiport

Tags: public-transport, transportation, airport-transfer, belgium, crl

How would you suggest reaching Spa (Belgium) from the Charleroi airport? I haven't found any shuttle option below 150 EUR, which is quite expensive. Is there a reasonably fast train connection?

I was focusing on Charleroi because flying there seems the cheapest/more comfortable option, but if you tell me that I'd be much better off from another airport I can reconsider. Spa seems to be almost equidistant from Brussels, Charleroi and Cologne. Liège and Maastricht are a bit closer but they are also much smaller airports, which means one more leg and more expensive flights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rome2Rio.com is great for searching for this sort of thing. The train station in Charleroi is a little south of the airport, so you'll probably have to take a bus or taxi to the train, but there's a good rail connection between the two cities. According to Rome2Rio, the bus and train will cost you under $50 USD (you can change currencies on the website through one of the settings).

http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Charleroi-Airport-CRL-Belgium/Spa

Comment: Really a great travel search engine, thanks for the tip!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're quoting fares in US dollars to a European asking about a journey within Europe.

Comment: There should be an option in Rome2Rio to change the display currency. As I'm at a U.S. IP address, it defaults to dollars.

Answer (score 3):

A stated by ColeS you can take the train. It's convenient and confortable. You will have to take the bus from the airport to the train station.

You can even travel cheaper though. The Charleroi has a special ticket that combines train and bus. It's fixed price for any place in Belgium and costs 19,10Euro.

[Check the train company website for more information.](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/tickets/to-charleroi-airport-ticket.aspx)

Comment: This is one of the times in which I wish I could accept two answers. This is good advice, too, thanks.